# mobile broadband signal strength indicator in ubuntu 15.10 weaker than in window 10

Tags: wireless, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 15.10 (kernel: 4.2) alongside with Window 10 in my new Aspire E15 E5-573G-779S. Appreciate if anyone can help to advise on below problem:
using usb modem - mobile broadband 3G MMS. Signal indicator in Ubuntu shows only 2 bars whereas window 10 shows 5 bars. In Ubuntu, the weak signal is proven as the browsing always fail with error "server-not-found" , whereas in Window, it is significantly fast and never fail in browsing.

Comment: why don't you test the speed in 'http://www.speedtest.net/'?

Comment: These "bars" show nothing. You can see the level in `iwconfig`.

Comment: results of iwconfig :
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wwx0250f3000000  no wireless extensions.

ppp0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Answer (score 0):

It's not a issue with Operation System . Windows have slow refresh rates than linux.This may make you feel that it's getting more signal strength on Windows than linux infact linux has better Services and memory management to provide you more speed than windows.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04LTS has much better browsing experience than that of 15.10, there is no "server not found" issue. Appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this problem in 15.10 as I am using Ubuntu 15.10 now. Thx.